# Changing the default layout for JFrame not working?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I was trying to change the default layout of the the `JFrame` from `BorderLayout` to `GridLayout` but the layout does not change.

Below is my code:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrameTest extends JFrame { 
    public JFrameTest() {       
        System.out.println("layout before is " + this.getLayout().toString());
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        System.out.println("layout after is " + this.getLayout().toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrameTest jft = new JFrameTest();
    }
}
```

The result of the code is:

```
layout before is java.awt.BorderLayout[hgap=0,vgap=0]
layout after is java.awt.BorderLayout[hgap=0,vgap=0]
```

Why is the layout not changing to `GridLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the Layout of the ContentPane and then checking the layout of the JFrame.

```
System.out.println("layout before is " + this.getContentPane().getLayout().toString());
this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
System.out.println("layout after is " + this.getContentPane().getLayout().toString());
```

This produces your desired result.

EDIT: The OP changed his original code making this answer not quite right.
In his case this would be the proper solution:

```
this.setRootPaneCheckingEnabled(false);
System.out.println("layout before is " + this.getLayout().toString());
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
System.out.println("layout after is " + this.getLayout().toString());
```

Comment: Sorry I wanted to change the default layout of the JFrame and no the content pane I have modified my code and still same problem

Comment: if you really want to set the layout of the frame and not the contentPane put this at the top of your constructor `this.setRootPaneCheckingEnabled(false);`